# H2 SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have a spring boot application with an h2 database that is addressed by a UserRepository. I am trying to use Spring security to authenticate using jdbc(Hibernate here)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")

public class User {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="USERNAME, nullable = false, unique = true")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    
    /*setter/getter follows */
}
```

Repository:-

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE USER(
    USER_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
```

INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES('jdoe','foobar');

```
But when enter correct username and password, it is not accepting it.

Exception:

SQL Error: 42001, SQLState: 42001
2022-03-04 13:43:18.571 ERROR 17924 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT USER0_.USER_ID AS USER_ID1_0_, USER0_.PASSWORD AS PASSWORD2_0_, USER0_.USERNAME, NULLABLE = FALSE, UNIQUE[*] = TRUE AS USERNAME3_0_ FROM USER USER0_ WHERE USER0_.USERNAME, NULLABLE = FALSE, UNIQUE = TRUE=? "; expected "*, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM, WITH"; SQL statement:
select user0_.user_id as user_id1_0_, user0_.password as password2_0_, user0_.username, nullable = false, unique = true as username3_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.username, nullable = false, unique = true=? [42001-196]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice mistake:

```
@Column(name="USERNAME, nullable = false, unique = true")
```

->

```
@Column(name="USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
```